# Extract the most recent records from the table

Tags: sql, database, join, amazon-redshift

I have two tables like this in sql:

customers:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | Karen A. |
| 456 | Lucas B. |
| 789 | Karen C. |
| 101 | Lucas D. |
| 111 | Karen E. |
| 112 | Lucas F. |
| 131 | Karen G. |

orders:

| fk_customer | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2022-08-01 |
| 123 | 2022-08-20 |
| 456 | 2022-09-13 |
| 456 | 2022-10-13 |
| 789 | 2022-08-15 |
| 789 | 2022-12-15 |
| 101 | 2023-01-15 |
| 111 | 2023-02-07 |
| 112 | 2022-12-09 |
| 112 | 2022-12-20 |
| 131 | 2021-05-02 |

note that in the ORDERS table the IDs are repeated.
I need a SELECT that brings only the most recent records from the table.

What I do in the query (which is necessary) is to get the maximum date from the customer.

```
SELECT top 3 csm.id as id_customer, csm.name as name , max(ord.created_at) as ord_created_at
FROM customers csm
LEFT JOIN orders ord ON ord.fk_customer = csm.id
group by 1
order by 3 desc
```

I need this TOP 3 to bring only the most recent records, like:

| id_customer | name | ord_created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Lucas D. | 2023-01-15 |
| 111 | Karen E. | 2023-02-07 |
| 112 | Lucas F. | 2022-12-20 |

but, what I gave something like:

| id_customer | name | ord_created_at |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | Lucas D. | 2023-01-15 |
| 123 | Karen A. | 2022-08-20 |
| 456 | Lucas B. | 2022-10-13 |

what can i do to get the most recent records from the table?

Answer (score 0):

If I read your description correctly, you miss [group by](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) operator in your query.

See the following code as example

```
SELECT 
    top 3 
    csm.id as id_customer, 
    max(csm.name) as name, 
    max(ord.created_at) as ord_created_at
FROM customers csm
LEFT JOIN orders ord ON ord.fk_customer = csm.id
GROUP BY csm.id
order by 3 desc
```

Answer (score 0):

you you are only interested in the last date you can use a subquery that gets you the date for evry customer

```
SELECT id,  name, maxdate
FROM cusromers c JOIN (SELECT fk_customer,  MAX(created_at) maxdate FROM ordes GROUPÜ BY fk_customer) o ON c.id = p.fk_customer
```

With a `LEFT JOIN` you would get all customers, even when they didn't order anything